# Header and Footer are not full pagewidth, when displayed on Tablet

Tags: css, responsive-design, joomla2.5, tablet

When looking at my [website](http://www.golfanatics.de) from a tablet, both header and footer are not covering the whole pagewidth. It is a pure CSS problem I assume, although not happening when browsing the site from a desktop PC (via Chrome for example).

I intend to have a full-page-width dark header and footer also on tablets (most importantly: iPad).

Any idea, what I would need to change to accomplish that?

Thank you & cheers, Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set

```
body { min-width: 1230px; }
```

And it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

OR

```
<meta 
    name="viewport" 
    content="width=1000, initial-scale=0.8, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Adjust it to your requirements.